# How to mock Cloud Azure storage Account using xunit

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, tdd, xunit

Please help me to mock below code:

original repo code we need to mock:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
CloudBlockBlob cloudBlobInstance = container.GetBlockBlobReference(container, imageName);
cloudBlobInstance.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length);
```

Modified repo code if Azure service wrapper injected:

```
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccountClient = _azureSeriveWrapper.GetStorageAccount("connString"); 
CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient  = _azureSeriveWrapper.GetBlobClient(cloudStorageAccountClient); 
CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer= _azureSeriveWrapper.GetBlobContainer(cloudBlobClient,"containerName");
 CloudBlockBlob cloudBlobInstance = _azureSeriveWrapper.GetBlockBlobReference(cloudBlobContainer, AssetImageName); 
 cloudBlobInstance.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length); 
 mediaUrl = cloudBlobInstance.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

It could have been done writing some wrapper and I have to change my existing code using interface but I need a sample piece of code as I am confused about how to set this.

I tried creating a wrapper but don't know how to mock.

Below code I tried to write to change the existing code:

```
public class AzureServiceWrapper : IAzureServiceWrapper
    {
        public CloudStorageAccount GetCloudStorageAccount(string connString)
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccountClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
            return cloudStorageAccountClient;
        }
        public CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(CloudBlobContainer storageContainer, string fileName)
        {
            //  CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccountClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);
            //  CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccountClient.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            //   CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);   
            //CloudBlobContainer storageContainer = GetBlobContainer(containerName);
            return storageContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        }
          public CloudBlobClient GetBlobClient(CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccountClient)
        {      
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccountClient.CreateCloudBlobClient();
           //  CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccountClient = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);    
            // CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccountClient.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            //     CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            return cloudBlobClient;
        }    

         public CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient, string containerName)
        {          
            //CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = _cloudStorageAccountClient.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
            return cloudBlobContainer;
        }
    }
}

Any help would be useful. 
Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to unit test and below are steps which might be useful to anyone reading:

**Step 1:**

Write all methods in the wrapper/interface and Inject interface in repository

```
CloudBlockBlob GetBlockBlobReference(CloudBlobContainer storageContainer, string fileName);
CloudStorageAccount GetCloudStorageAccount(string connString);
CloudBlobContainer GetBlobContainer(CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient, string containerName);
CloudBlobClient GetBlobClient(CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccountClient);
SharedAccessBlobPolicy GetSharedAccessBlobPolicy();
string GetSharedAccessSignature(CloudBlockBlob blockBlob, SharedAccessBlobPolicy sasConstraints);
```

**Step 2:**

Mock all as below:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://test.com/");

string connectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=text;AccountKey=test";

var storageAcctReference = new Mock<IAzureServiceWrapper>();

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);

StorageCredentials storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials(accountName: "blah", keyValue: "blah");

storageAcctReference.Setup(x => x.GetCloudStorageAccount(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(storageAccount);

storageAcctReference.Setup(x => x.GetBlobClient(It.IsAny<CloudStorageAccount>())).Returns(new CloudBlobClient(uri));
   
storageAcctReference.Setup(x => x.GetBlobContainer(It.IsAny<CloudBlobClient>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new CloudBlobContainer(uri, storageCredentials));

storageAcctReference.Setup(x => x.GetSharedAccessBlobPolicy()).Returns(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy());
            
storageAcctReference.Setup(x => x.GetSharedAccessSignature(It.IsAny<CloudBlockBlob>(), It.IsAny<SharedAccessBlobPolicy>())).Returns("sastest-token1");

storageAcctReference.Setup(x => x.GetBlockBlobReference(It.IsAny<CloudBlobContainer>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new CloudBlockBlob(uri, storageCredentials));
```

**Step 3:**

Pass/Inject wrapper reference to repository and use that instead of actual implementation to call cloud storage different methods(as above)